# Java.Type cannot be resolved when trying to ipmlement java proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, web-crawler

I use Java 8 and eclipse Neon.1 Release (4.6.1) .

I am trying to create a proxy object but for some reason the IDE shows a run time error saying Type cannot be resolved  . 
here is the code :

```
  import java.net.*;
public class extracter{

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("123.0.0.1", 8080));

}
```

appreciate all the help i can get

Comment: What's the full, exact error message? And it's at runtime, not from the `Problems` View?

Comment: yes its at runtime , the error reads :
 
 Type cannot be resolved or is not 
  a field

Comment: Can you show *that*? Because there's no `main` method here to run.

Comment: this is a screen shot http://imgur.com/a/EmtUq

Answer (score 0):

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB9fu.jpg

1) That is *not* a runtime error. That's feedback within the editor itself. It would be called development time, or edit time.

2) You are already importing a different type named `Proxy`, which collides with `Proxy` from the `java.net` package. Keep your `import` statements clean (use `Organize Imports` from the `Source` menu), and give complete source examples in the future.